# Columns mentioned in DataGrid.Columns is not visible when AutoGenerateColumns=false in CustomControl DataGrid (WPF Datagrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to Create a Custom Control by extending the DataGrid in WPF, but the problem is that when I use this custom control in view and Provide the specific columns by setting the AutoGenerateColumns to False, the columns is not getting generated. In the OnApplyTemplate() when I tried to fetch the Datagrid through the Template it shows as column count as 0, whereas in the view in code behind it shows the no of columns correctly whatever is specified in the xaml. 
Where I am wrong or something extra needs to be set for this?

My Custom control code-

```
public class DataGridControl: DataGrid
 {
    static DataGridControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DataGridControl)));
    }

   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        DataGrid dataGrid = Template.FindName("PART_DataGrid", this) as DataGrid;
        int noOfColumns = dataGrid.Columns.Count// (0 it should come as 3)
    }

}
```

Generic.xaml(inside the Control Template and border)

```
 <ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
.....
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Siemens.WPF.DataGridControl">
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="lightBrushBack" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    .....
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="normalBrushBack" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
   ......
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="PART_DataGrid"

                                  ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                   AutoGenerateColumns="{TemplateBinding AutoGenerateColumns}">
                            <DataGrid.Resources>

                                <!--A custom DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter is required to "not" display the custom ColumnHeader template as background of the datagrid header-->
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <!--"part_fillercolumnheader" (DataGridColumnHeader type) is removed, and a plain rectangle is placed in its place.-->
                                                    <Rectangle  Fill="{StaticResource normalBrushBack}" />
                                                    <!--Leave the item presenter in its place.-->
                                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                                <!--End of custom DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter template-->

                                <!--Custom Column Header Gripper styling-->
                                <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>

                                <!--Custom Column Header template to show extra elements in the header-->
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

                                                <!--Let's keep the top section grid to contain the DataGridHeaderBorder, and left+right thumbs.-->
                                                <Grid x:Name="fullHeader" Background="{StaticResource normalBrushBack}">

                                                    <!--Here is the theme based DataGridHeaderBorder. I've used Aero here.-->
                                                    <aero:DataGridHeaderBorder x:Name='HeaderBorder'
                                                           SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
                                                           IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                                           IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                                           IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
                                                           BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                                                           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                           Background="Transparent"
                                                           SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"
                                                           SeparatorBrush="#FFC9CACA">

                                                        <!--Put 3 elements inside the border: Content of header, a drop down button, and a sort order indicator.-->
                                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition MinHeight="15" Height="20" />
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <!--For ContentPresenter-->
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                                <!--For drop down button-->
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                                                                <!--For sort order indicator-->
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12" />
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                            <!--A hidden rectangle is placed to be shown when mouse hovers on the column (to highlight the column.)-->
                                                            <Rectangle x:Name="HoverRectangle"
                                                                    Stretch="Fill"
                                                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                                                    Fill="{StaticResource lightBrushBack}"
                                                                    Opacity="0"
                                                                    StrokeThickness="0" />

                                                            <!--Content of the header.-->
                                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                                                              Grid.Row="0"
                                                                              Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                                  Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" />

                                                            <!--A drop down filter button.-->
                                                            <Button x:Name="PART_FilterBtn" 
                                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                    Command="{Binding FilterClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}"
                                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=HeaderBorder}"
                                                                    Grid.Row="0" Cursor="Hand"
                                                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                                                <Button.Template>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                                        <Path Data="M 0,0 L 1,1 1,3 2,3 2,1 3,0 Z"
                                                                              Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                                                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                                              Margin="4,4,0,4"/>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                                </Button.Template>
                                                            </Button>

                                                            <Path x:Name="PART_SortArrow"
                                                                  Grid.Column="2"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                                  Width="8"
                                                                  RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
                                                                  Visibility="Visible"
                                                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                                  Stretch="Uniform"
                                                                  Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z">
                                                            </Path>

                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </aero:DataGridHeaderBorder>

                                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                                                </Grid>

                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="PART_SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Trigger>

                                                    <Trigger Property='IsMouseOver' SourceName="fullHeader" Value='True'>
                                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.20000"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                 To='1.0' />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.20000"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                 To='0' />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush options:Freeze="True" StartPoint="0.504,0.03" EndPoint="0.504,1.5">
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#E3F7FF" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#E3F7FF" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.35" Color="#BCECFE" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#B9E9FC" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#69BBE3" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                                <!--End of custom DataGridColumnHeader template-->

                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_PopUp" 
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                AllowDrop="True" 
                                Width="200"
                                Height="253"
                                MinHeight="253"
                                MaxHeight="253"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide"
                                VerticalOffset="-15"
                                IsOpen="{Binding IsFilterPopUpVisible,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DataGridControl}}"
                                PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_FilterBtn}"
                                StaysOpen="False"
                                Placement="Mouse" >
                            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,5,0,5">
                                        <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="PART_SelectAllBtn" Command="{Binding SelectAllClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PART_ListBox}" >
                                            <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Select All" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Button.Template>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Margin="30,0,0,0" Name="PART_SelectNoneBtn" Command="{Binding SelectNoneClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PART_ListBox}" >
                                            <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Select None" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Button.Template>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Width="185" Height="25" Text="" Margin="3,0,3,3"/>
                                    <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" 
                                             Height="160" 
                                             MaxHeight="160" 
                                             MinHeight="160" 
                                             Width="185" 
                                             SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                                             DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                             HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                             VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                             VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding FilterCollectionList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                                                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
                                                            <CheckBox x:Name="PART_CheckBox" Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                                                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}"/>
                                                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}"/>
                                                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                                <ContentPresenter />
                                                            </CheckBox>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    </ListBox>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_OkBtn" Height="22" Width="70" Content="Ok" 
                                                                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsOkButtonEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}"
                                                                                    Command="{Binding OkButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}"
                                                                                     />
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_CancelBtn" Height="22" Width="70" Content="Cancel" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                                                                    Command="{Binding CancelButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridControl}}}" 
                                                                                    />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <dataGrid:DataGridControl x:Name="dataGridControl" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <dataGrid:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RollNo" Binding="{Binding RollNo}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        </dataGrid:DataGridControl.Columns>
    </dataGrid:DataGridControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Student> studList =
        new List<Student>() {  new Student {  RollNo = 1, Name = "Full Name 
        1", FirstName = "FirstName1", LastName="LastName1", Address = 
        "Pune1", PinCode= "411057"},};

        dataGridControl.ItemsSource = studList; 
         int noOfColumns = dataGridControl.Columns.Count; //(showing 3 as expected)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The columns have not yet been created when the template is applied. How is your template defined and what custom functionality are you trying to add?

Comment: I am trying to create a Custom DataGrid having column search functionality like MS Excel. I achieved that, but later on I found I am unable to have control over the column that is being displayed using dataGrid.columns. If I set Autogenerate columns to true then whatever column is there in Items source get rendered.

Comment: Your issue is that a template of a custom DataGrid should not contain another DataGrid element...

Comment: hmm..It seems so, but If I remove the DataGrid from the template than the DateGrid doesn't renders using custom control reference. Also If I keep only the style part and reference it in the DataGrid with the component resource key the code behind of Generic i.e. the CustomControl1.cs OnApplyTemplate() method or other overrided mehtod doesn't gets called, where I have other functionality like command binding and others written.

Comment: What is custom about your template? I have already asked how your template is defined once but you still haven't posted your actual and complete template.

Comment: Updated the full Template code(Generic.xaml) above. and on the click of button fetching the current column data and displaying it in the popup and doing the filter operation and resets the Datagrid ItemsSource.

Comment: You could copy the default template of the DataGrid by right-clicking on it in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Create property for custom control

```
 #region GridColumns

 private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _gridColumns;
 public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GridColumns
 {
     get => _gridColumns;
 }

 #endregion GridColumns
```

Add columns from created property using method OnApplyTemplate

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
     base.OnApplyTemplate();

     if (!AutoGenerateColumns)
     {
         var grid = GetTemplateChild("PART_Grid") as DataGrid;
         foreach (var column in _gridColumns)
             grid.Columns.Add(column);
     }
 }
```

Change MainWindow.xaml

```
<dataGrid:DataGridControl x:Name="dataGridControl" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <dataGrid:DataGridControl.GridColumns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RollNo" Binding="{Binding RollNo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </dataGrid:DataGridControl.GridColumns>
</dataGrid:DataGridControl>
```